# String.Join and String.Split parameter mnemonic

Tags: c#, string, mnemonics

I trip on C#'s String.Join and String.Split parameter types every time.  The problem is that `String.Split` takes a `params char[]` array of characters and `String.Join` takes a `string`.

Does anyone have a good mnemonic that can help me remember which takes which so I do not have to fix this *every single time* I do a string manipulation?

**[EDIT, since everyone seems to be confused why I don't have IDE support]**

I'm using LinqPad, like this, when I use this most of the time:

```
String.Join("\n", @"LongRawString
WithPlentyOfLines
UsuallyGeneratedBySomeoneElse
OrProducedBySqlServerForExample".Split('\n').Select(x => 
    {
        x = x.Trim();

        //create line of code, like:
        return "int longRawStringIdx = reader.GetOrdinal(\"LongRawString\")";
    }))
```

I don't get IDE support in LinqPad, and would like to save the few seconds it takes me to go back and fix it every time.  It's silly, but then so are half the scripts that we programmers write to automate the 12 second tasks we do every day.

The problem is that I screw up whether or not I'm supposed to be giving `Split` the `string` or `Join` the `string` as its first parameter (or only in the case of `Split`).

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The IDE shows the accepted parameters...

Comment: You could always define your own extension methods and make it work however you want

Comment: String.Join is static, the other is not, isn't it enough that you know that?

Comment: There's more than one situation where you don't get IDE support.  For example I use linq pad to generate code from other data (line by line manipulation with C#'s regex support is way more powerful than Notepad++, for example). But, when you're working in LinqPad you don't have Intellisense unless you pay for it (which I haven't yet).

Comment: You still didn't specify what your problem is. Are you using string instead of char or the other way around or something else completely?

Comment: Have you considered paying the modest fee for autocompletion in LINQPad? See http://www.linqpad.net/Purchase.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could think of it this way: you're specifying *one* thing to join on, but *several* possible delimiters to split on. It makes sense that way round as the input string could already have many delimiters, but it doesn't make sense to join on multiple delimiters, as the `Join` method would have to work out which delimiter you meant each time.

I'd just use Intellisense though :)

Comment: That's very helpful.  Thanks Jon.  I came from a C++/Python NLP background where we either rolled our own Split/Join (in C++, since we were dealing with enormous amounts of data), or we used the Python Split/Join, which are so quirky that I remembered them immediately.